# Angular: Add resolver to a route less component

Tags: angular

I am working on an app where I have three different routes for a lazy loaded module. I am using router-outlet to display those routes and have a static component that remains the same through out these three routes. I want to access the data from the resolver in my static component but, I am getting `undefined`.

Here's the code:

> static.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    const data = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['deliveryData'];
    console.log(data);    //undefined, since it's not a route
}
```

> cart.resolver.ts

```
resolve(): Observable<any>{
    const payload = xyz;
    return this.http.postHttpRequest(payload);
}
```

The page looks like something like this:

```
- <router-outlet></router-outlet>
- <static-component></static-component>
```

Therefore, I cannot use output. How can I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to go with services.

Create a shared service and set the delivery data using `setDeliveryData(data)` when you want and we can get the data in static component similar way like below.

**service.ts**

```
deliveryData: any = {};

publish void setDeliveryData(data : any) {
   this.deliveryData = data;
}
```

**static.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    const data = this.sharedService.getDeliveryData();
    console.log(data);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by declaring the static component as an `Auxiliary Route`.